# ctags tag address as a line number

Tags: ctags, universal-ctags

I am creating an IDE and I wish to implement jump to definition.

I found the perfect tool for it: ctags (https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags)

Now the only problem is that the tags file that ctags create looks something like this:

`QLineNumberArea 2point56mb.py   /^class QLineNumberArea(QWidget):$/;"   c`

I understand the format: {tagname}Tab{tagfile}Tab{tagaddress}

So from what I understand: `tagname`: QLineNumberArea, `tagfile`: 2point56mb.py and `tagaddress`: /^class QLineNumberArea(QWidget):$/;"   c`

The tagaddress looks like gibberish but it's a vim/ex editor command that takes you to the definition.

Now from what I read on this website: https://github.com/cztchoice/ctags/wiki/Tag-Format

Under `Security` it states:

`Specifically, these two Ex commands are allowed:`

`A decimal line number:`

`89`
`A search command. It is a regular expression pattern, as used by Vi, enclosed in // or ??:`

`/^int c;$/`
`?main()?`

Now here comes the problem:

I need my tags file to have a line number, instead of the search command.
I tried looking the documentation for ctags (http://docs.ctags.io/en/latest/) but I couldn't find anything that would help me.

Does anyone know how make ctags give tag addresses as a line number, rather than a search command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That documentation is only for the changes introduced by universal ctags. What you're looking for is the documentation for [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html):

```
−−excmd=type

Determines the type of EX command used to locate tags in the source file. [Ignored in etags mode]
```

Which can also be achieved with `-n`.